# drupal  shows empty content because of memcache

Tags: 6, caching

I have a Drupal (pressflow 6.22) website and I am using memcache as a caching level for my website/server. Sometimes some node (articles) that has been published on my website shows empty content when browsed (Specially with IE).

When I do below on the server that has memcache

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
flush_all
OK
quit
```

and refresh the page using the same browser, it is displayed properly. Has anybody faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Walter Jenner: memcached should be flushed from time to another, so i have fixed it by applying the following crontabs

```
0 */1 * * * echo "flush_all" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
1 */1 * * * ps aux |grep flush_all | grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
1 */1 * * * ps aux |grep "nc 127.0.0.1 11211" | grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed and configured drupal with the module for memcache - http://drupal.org/project/memcache ?

There is also a handbook page that will be able to help you http://drupal.org/node/1131458

Comment: sure i did... 
but honestly memcached caused a lot of troubles for me. and this is one of them :(. it reduces my average server load exponentially which is great. but in the same time it caused a lot of problems

Answer (score 2):

We recently went through a through troubleshooting of this issue.

We found that the fields table should not be served from Memcached.

$conf['cache_class_cache_field'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/node/1679344#comment-7895709

Comment: same issue i am facing ..i am using drupal 8 .. can you tell  how field table should not be cached